# Is there a way to simplify $urlRouterProvider.when?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
    $urlRouterProvider
.when('/EcoCOOL', '/ecocool')
.when('/ECOCOOL', '/ecocool')
.when('/EcoCool', '/ecocool')
.when('/EcoCOOL/USA', '/ecocool/USA')
.when('/ECOCOOL/USA', '/ecocool/USA')
.when('/EcoCool/USA', '/ecocool/USA')
.when('/EcoCOOL/Europe', '/ecocool/Europe')
.when('/ECOCOOL/Europe', '/ecocool/Europe')
.when('/EcoCool/Europe', '/ecocool/Europe')
.when('/EcoCOOL/Asia', '/ecocool/Asia')
.when('/ECOCOOL/Asia', '/ecocool/Asia')
.when('/EcoCool/Asia', '/ecocool/Asia')
.when('/EcoCOOL/UAE', '/ecocool/UAE')
.when('/ECOCOOL/UAE', '/ecocool/UAE')
.when('/EcoCool/UAE', '/ecocool/UAE')
.when('/EcoCOOL/Canada', '/ecocool/Canada')
.when('/ECOCOOL/Canada', '/ecocool/Canada')
.when('/EcoCool/Canada', '/ecocool/Canada')
```

Is there a way to check EcoCOOL first?  make all of them lower case.  then I only have to run 1 rule for the countries.  ie /ecocool/MyCountry.  rather than checking 3 different spellings of the word and then the country?

ie..  is there a shorter way to do this?  like using * or /*/ etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [`rule()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#rule-for-custom-url-handling) - custom url handling:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // Here's an example of how you might allow case insensitive urls
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        var path = $location.path(), normalized = path.toLowerCase();
        if (path != normalized) return normalized;
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks! i'll check it out tonight and i'll rep you up when it works

Comment: ok, i just popped that badboy in the code and everything is lowercase. Perfect.  Just what i needed!